# Struts error: There is no Action mapped for namespace / and action name ***

Tags: java, jsp, struts2

I am newbie to struts and jsp.
Currently i am stuck on the above error its screwing me badly from last two weeks, dont know what i am doing wrong.
Here's what i am trying to do:

temp.jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">

<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Sample Page</title>
</head>

<body>
Hello World
<br/>

<A href="myAction.action"><font face="arial" color="black" size=2>Run</font></A>
</body>
</html>
```

In this page i have href link "Run" and when i click on this link it will call my action which finally calls my test.jsp page.

test.jsp

```
  <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
!!!! Hello !!!!
</body>
</html>
```

struts.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<struts>
<constant name="struts.devMode" value="true" />
<package name="TestWeb" extends="struts-default" namespace="/">
    <action name="myAction">
        <result>/test.jsp</result></action></package>
</struts>
```

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app id="WebApp_ID" version="2.4" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">
    <display-name>TestWeb</display-name>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
    <filter>
        <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.FilterDispatcher</filter-class>
    </filter>

     <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Friends please help me with this.

Comment: Show us the struts.xml. And the url your are hitting. Include more details in the question.

Comment: Use **code** button (the `{}` one) and please... indent your html :/

Comment: Your Struts 2 config file is mal-formed. You are using the deprecated filter. Are you deploying to the root context? If not, you should include the app context in the URL. Two weeks to get a working app when the framework ships with examples?

Comment: @DaveNewton sorry i didnt get u, will u pls elaborate.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
 <package name="default" extends="struts-default" namespace="/">
           <action name="myAction" 
        class="com.action.MyAction" >
        <result name="success">result.jsp</result>
    </action>

</package>
```

In JSP

```
<a href="<s:url action="myAction"/>">click here</a>
```

OR  (@tom 's suggestion)

```
<s:a action="myAction" >click here</s:a>
```

Also, make sure that `struts.xml` configuration file is on the classpath

Comment: its there in struts.xml file.

Comment: What you wrote works but I find the following syntax is better: `<s:a action="myAction" >click here</s:a>`

Comment: @tom: Thanks for the suggestion. I will update that to answer

Answer (score -1):

Make sure to add ActionServlet in your web.xml and in your temp.jsp, change the href to myaction.

Comment: will you please elaborate, as i am newbee i am not getting what are you saying.

Comment: Struts 2 does not use an action servlet, rather a filter.